# How to get excel table data in to a LIST in c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I want to get excel table values to a list in c#

here is my code

```
           [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetExcelData()
    {
        List<ExcelData> exData = new List<ExcelData>();

         string status;
        string fileparth;
        string json;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        JObject jo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        fileparth = jo.Value<string>("uplaodFile");
        string conString = string.Empty;

        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileparth);

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'", fileparth);

                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'", fileparth);

                break;

        }
      //  conString = string.Format(conString/*strConnection*/, fileparth/*FileUpload1*/);
        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

            //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.

            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { 
                new DataColumn("TRID", typeof(decimal)),
                 new DataColumn("Actual(km)", typeof(string)),
                  new DataColumn("Amount(Rs)", typeof(decimal))
            });
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }
            excel_con.Close();
        }
    }
```

after                   excel_con.Close();

i need to go through a loop until the recourds are end in the sheet.
then i need to add these values to

exData

these are the getters and setters

```
                 public class ExcelData
    {
        private decimal _RnEID;

        public decimal RnEID
        {
            get { return _RnEID; }
            set { _RnEID = value; }
        }
        private string _EActual;

        public string EActual
        {
            get { return _EActual; }
            set { _EActual = value; }
        }
        private string _EAmount;

        public string EAmount
        {
            get { return _EAmount; }
            set { _EAmount = value; }
        }
    }
```

here i the dummy excel sheet

[image]

please help me to solve this matter

thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the DataTable is unnecessary if you want to return a `List<ExcelData>`.

Effectively a DataAdapter.Fill method loops over the returned data using an internal OleDbDataReader and fills the DataTable. Now, if you want to return a `List<ExcelData>` you need to loop again on the table and build an element of type ExcelData for every row in the table.

So, you could do it yourself without the loop required by the adapter fill method.

```
    List<ExcelData> exData = new List<ExcelData>();
    .....

    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDBCommand())
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]";
        cmd.Connection = excel_con;
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
             ExcelData curLine = new ExcelData();
             curLine.RnEID = (reader.IsDbNull(0) ? 0m : Convert.ToDecimal(reader[0]));
             curLine.EActual = (reader.IsDbNull(1) ? "" : reader[1].ToString());
             curLine.EAmount = (reader.IsDbNull(2) ? 0m : Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]));
             exData.Add(curLine);
        }
    }
    return exData;
```

Having empty cells could cause an error message for null values. You could check and prevent the error message using OleDbDataReader.IsDbNull method

Comment: but on the run time it give this error                                    No data exists for the row/column.                                           it come from this place                   curLine.RnEID = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[0]);

Comment: The message could be caused by empty rows or columns. If you have this situation then you need to check with IsDbNull

Comment: If you open the Excel sheet and press CTRL+END, where do you see your active cell? Is on a valid cell or is on an empty cell? If it is empty then [look at this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/reset-the-last-cell-of-your-excel-worksheet/)

Comment: it was c,10 colume which have 85 value

Comment: Then it is real difficult to say what's happening here. Try using the debugger and check on which line/cell you get the error. If it is possibile you could also upload the excel file to some sharing host and post a link here so I could try it.

Comment: steve i have a proble in this code in my excle file i have many records so do i need to loop this for each row of excel file                      ExcelData curLine = new ExcelData();
             curLine.RnEID = (reader.IsDbNull(0) ? 0m : Convert.ToDecimal(reader[0]));
             curLine.EActual = (reader.IsDbNull(1) ? "" : reader[1].ToString());
             curLine.EAmount = (reader.IsDbNull(2) ? 0m : Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]));
             exData.Add(curLine);

Comment: Add a counter that you increment at each loop, add a try/catch and in the catch display the value of counter. You should have a good guess at the problem point

Comment: ok thank you steve i'll check it. here is the link of the file  https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rxc7qsmicajbsc/TRTESTs.xls?dl=0

Comment: thanks steve the problem is we must loop for the data adding part. so now it working thaks stave for your help from the Begin. thank a lot